# Alternatives to iCloud + Core Data to sync data between iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I'm developing an application for iOS/OS X and i want to sync data between them.
for now I use Core Data for persistent data.
I read that iCloud is not enough mature to use with core data.

1. Is that true ?

so i try to use the new DropBox sync API(to sync the SQLite file), but there's no support for OS X.

1. Is Parse SDK a good idea? (it will also allow me to add Android support)
2. If no, have you other solution?

Thank you.

Comment: what is wrong with the _iCloud_...?

Comment: why the down vote? i'm just asking to have clear idea before using iCloud!! and in this site : https://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452 the author say: "I do not recommend you to use this feature in a production environment" and in the last comment he say the that icloud+core data still buggy.

Comment: @holex It would make more sense to ask what is right about iCloud with Core Data. It has numerous problems right now.

Comment: @TomHarrington, any specific details, please?

Comment: Examples: http://www.openradar.me/13102447 and http://www.openradar.me/13119691 are two of the more serous issues I've run into. There are many more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> i read that icloud is not enough mature to use with core data.
>
> is that true ?

Yes, I've worked with it quite a bit but I cannot recommend it at present.

> so i try to use the new dropBox sync API(to sync the sqlite file), but there's no support for mac.
>
> 1. is parse sdk a good idea (that will allow me to add android support)?
> 2. if no, have you other solution ?

Parse has a good reputation. There's an open source project called [FTASync](https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync) that integrates it with Core Data.

Some other options:

- [TICoreDataSync](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync), which syncs via Dropbox but lets you use Core Data
- [WasabiSync](http://www.wasabisync.com), a third-party project that syncs Core Data via their own servers.
- [Simperium](https://simperium.com), another one like Wasabi, syncing Core Data via their own servers.

At present I don't have enough experience with any of these to endorse them. They're all designed to sync Core Data outside of iCloud but I can't say which works best.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, i think i'll see if i can use iCloud without problems,else i'll use TICoreDataSync because with parse user have to create a new account(many user have dropBox account).

Comment: It's your call of course, but I really could not recommend iCloud with Core Data in current versions of iOS or Mac OS X. I really hope they can get it fixed, but for now I'd steer clear.

Comment: it's really confusing to see a major service buggy like you and other say :(

Comment: Tom, did anything change after iOS 7, is iCloud still not good?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to really beat on it and see how it holds up. After iOS 5 and iOS 6, clients are less interested in paying for iCloud-related development. The WWDC 2013 announcements were encouraging, but that's about all I can say for sure.

Comment: WWDC 2013 made iCloud more promising, but I'm not seeing people start to adopt it. Thanks for your comments, and I'm reading your post about Dropbox datastore in your blog, maybe another option.

Comment: I'm started working with iCloud from iOS7 and can't say that I'm happy. I've got at least 1 sync stuck in iOS simulator.

Comment: And they have gone and broken iCloud badly AGAIN in Yosemite/IOS8. These do not play nice together.

Comment: elcapitan and ios 9, the problems persist.

i went throught all the APIs and services listed above and being a first time developer i find them very overwhelming. i am stuck! i have build an entire app centered around core data (which works perfectly fine) but icloud just doesn't work fine! 

i want to make it rather simple... just backup the persistent store to some cloud service where user can manually restore it upon reinstallation of the app. 

I dont wanna ship an incomplete app that doesnt give users a chance to backup their data. HELP!

Comment: @AceNeerav you should ask a new question that describes your problem in detail, including what you have attempted and exactly what went wrong.

Comment: @TomHarrington i havent tried anything but the same, attempt to use core data with iCloud. Thus the comment and not the question. Duplicate questions get voted down very fast on stack-overflow.

Comment: Any new alternatives in this late 2015 or has one of these options stand out?